# How to to request GoogleMaps tiles as a XYZ tile service?

Tags: google-maps, openlayers-3

I have a client who has an Enterprise license with Google, which I suppose give them access to the GoogleMaps for Work product.

I want to use OpenLayers 3 as JavaScript map engine to query tiles from GoogleMaps as a XYZ any other tile provider would.  I.E. I don't want to use the GoogleMaps library to request the tiles. I heard once that this could be possible if one was a "Google Premier" customer.

I've been searching GoogleMaps documentation for this but I haven't found anything yet. I don't know the exact name of the service/feature I'm looking for, so it's hard to search. I'm also not a hundred percent sure it's even possible to do so.

In summary:

- can GoogleMaps tiles be loaded using a XYZ service if one has the proper license ?
- what is the required license ?
- where can I find documentation about this ?
- are there any example of use of this somewhere ?

Thank you very much

Comment: As far as we know this is not possible.

Comment: Here's an old topic where I first asked about the integration of GoogleMaps within ol3.  That's where I first learn that it could be possible to use tiles directly: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ol3-dev/_Gx3_vYj0ys/Nru9Jkfh2XYJ  Is it the case ?

Comment: Yes back then we thought it was possible, but Google doesn't seem to offer any way unfortunately for this type of integration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Bart.  Just to be sure, we'll try contact Google directly and ask them.  Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks, please report what they say.

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to give an answer, as I couldn't ask them directly by myself (I had to ask a client who has the enterprise licence to do the dirty task for me and he couldn't in the end).  I'm a little disappointed to not be able to give a straight answer.  I'm sorry about that.  If I ever get one, I'll post it here.